# how do i hook linkbutton oncommand event to another method say gridview OnPageIndexChanging event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `LinkButton` where I handle the `Command` event. I also have a `GridView`where I'm handling the `PageIndexChanging` event. I want to call the `LinkButton`'s `Command` handler from the `GridView`'s  `PageIndexChanging` Handler. How do I do this?

```
//Code-behind of my LinkButton Command handler

Protected Sub Linkprodcat1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)    
    If e.CommandName = "select" Then
        //do something
    End if 
End Sub


//Code-behind of my GridView PageIndexChanging handler
//Here I want to call the the LinkButton's Command handler method 

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    If Me.pageindexselctoption.Value = "product1" Then
        Call Linkprodcat1_Command(sender, e) //this does not work
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Call Linkprodcat1_Command(sender, e)` won't work because `e` here is of the type `GridViewPageEventArgs`. `Linkprodcat1_Command` is expecting its second argument to by of the type `CommandEventArgs`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
Protected Sub Linkprodcat1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "select" Then
        SelectCommand()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    If Me.pageindexselctoption.Value = "product1" Then
        SelectCommand()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub SelectCommand()
    'Do something
End Sub
```